# Mysql get multiple counts from stats database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get unique counts along with country counts and sum rate for every user

I have come up with this basic design for database where `uid` is user id

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `stats`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `country` int(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ip` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `rate` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `stats` 
(`id`, `uid`, `country`, `ip`, `date`, `timestamp`, `rate`) VALUES
(1, 1, 10, 1111111111, 2222222222, 3333333333, 100),
(2, 1, 10, 1111111112, 2222222222, 3333333333, 100),
(3, 2, 10, 1111111111, 2222222222, 3333333333, 100),
(4, 1, 10, 1111111114, 2222222223, 3333333333, 100),
(5, 1, 11, 1111111112, 2222222223, 3333333333, 100),
(6, 1, 10, 1111111111, 2222222223, 3333333333, 100);
```

And this is the query I am using to fetch daily counts

```
$query="
SELECT `uid`,
COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`)AS `count`, 
`country`, 
SUM(`rate`) AS `sum`,
`date`
FROM `stats` 
GROUP BY `uid`, `date`
";
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo 'userid:'.$row['uid'].' count:'.$row['count'].' country:'.$row['country'].' sum:'.$row['sum'].' date:'.$row['date'].'<br>';
};
```

I am getting this result

```
userid:1 count:2 country:10 sum:200 date:2222222222
userid:1 count:3 country:10 sum:300 date:2222222223
userid:2 count:1 country:10 sum:100 date:2222222222
```

Expected result

```
userid:1 count:2 country:10=>2        sum:200 date:2222222222
userid:1 count:3 country:10=>2, 11=>1 sum:300 date:2222222223
userid:2 count:1 country:10=>1        sum:100 date:2222222222
```

I guess I need something like `SELECT DISTINCT country FROM stats` to get country counts in main query.

Please see and suggest any possible way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to count distinct countries too?

Comment: @Strawberry yes but result should be displayed in single row fro a day for any user

Comment: And how do you know which date corresponds to which result

Comment: @Strawberry I have date column for that and I am using it on group by

Comment: But it's not in the SELECT, is it. My sense is that, if you think about it for a bit, you'll figure out how to solve all of this for yourself

Comment: @Strawberry I need something like `SELECT DISTINCT country FROM stats` to get country counts in main query.

Comment: You're confusing issues of data retrieval with those of data display. In general, the latter are best handled in application level code, where that's available (a simple PHP loop in this instance).

Comment: @Strawberry Yes php loop can do it but what if rows are in millions, Can php handle that with loop for many users as fast as mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subquery to achieve this:

```sql
SELECT
  t.uid,
  SUM(t.count) AS count,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(t.country, ' => ', t.views) SEPARATOR ', ') AS country,
  SUM(t.sum) as sum,
  t.date
FROM (
  SELECT
    s.uid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT s.ip) AS count,
    s.country,
    COUNT(s.country) as views,
    SUM(s.rate)AS sum,
    s.date
  FROM stats s
  GROUP BY uid, date, country
  ) AS t
GROUP BY
t.uid,
t.date
```

Also available at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45c03/7).

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I also want to know will it work on millions of rows properly and frequently so that database does not become slow.

Comment: Performance depends on how many rows will be grouped in one. MySQL will perform subquery first. And then outer query will be executed on result dataset. If first query returns many rows, second can take significal amount of time. If first query with grouping returns few rows, then second query will be fast and almost no affects total execution time.

Comment: So that means for millions of rows with many user it will be slow

Answer (score 1):

SUM needs a column and you gave string `'rate'` in it, remove the `'` from rate column name try this,

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`)AS `count`, 
  `country`, 
  SUM(rate) AS `sum` 
  FROM `stats` 
  GROUP BY `uid`, `date`
```

Comment: Thanks it was a typo mistake and that's solves the sum  but I still need country counts

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add `country` into the GROUP condition too:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`) AS `count`,
    `country`,
    COUNT(`country`) as `countryViewsByUser`,   -- added
    SUM(`rate`)AS `sum`
FROM
    `stats`
GROUP BY
    `uid`,
    `date`,
    `country`   -- added
```

Comment: This gives one extra row for same day, I need all data in one row for a day.

Comment: `userid:1 count:2 country:10 sum:200
userid:1 count:2 country:10 sum:200
userid:1 count:1 country:11 sum:100
userid:2 count:1 country:10 sum:100`

Comment: It gives 4 rows, and that is what your data will give. 2 rows for day 1, 2 rows for day 2.

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to add country to your group by clause like below

```
$query="
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT `ip`)AS `count`, 
`country`,
COUNT(DISTINCT `country`) AS country_count, 
SUM(`rate`) AS `sum` 
FROM `stats` 
GROUP BY `country`, `uid`, `date`
";
```

And please you need to move away from mysqli_* functions, and take a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

Comment: it does not give all data for a user in one row instead in two rows